# Hide permission popup in android M/N

Tags: android, permissions

Is there any way in Android M/N to hide the permission popup .
I completely understands that Android M onwards it has a new security modal and it mandates run time permissions check for dangerous permissions. But I did not find anything related to hide/suppress the popup.

After reading the material on developer documentation(link below) I found that only normal permission can be pre granted by System without asking from user. But for others e.g. Camera, Network, Media files etc. we MUST get permission from user which I'm trying to avoid for better user experience.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

All I'm trying to understand that is there any way to create an app with higher privilege or make modification in AOSP or anything we can do to suppress the permission popup in Android M or N?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so - I would be surprised to learn of anything, this exactly contradicts Google's philosophies and all the steps they are trying to take forward with the platform. I'm going to monitor this question, as I'm very curios of any developments.

Answer (score 1):

Only with root permissions.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"pm grant com.example.app android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION\"");
```

Comment: Hey Dima, Thanks for the answer. I'll try and let you know.